# How to wrap this controller logic inside a angular function and use it in select html element

Tags: angularjs

How to wrap this controller logic inside a angular function and use it in select html element. Here inside controller code is use as inline logic without function.

Controller:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var range = [];
range.push(year);
for(var i=1;i<20;i++) {
  range.push(year + i);
}
$scope.years = range;
```

View:

```
<select ng-options="year for year in years">
</select>
```

Comment: why do you think they add the custom directives to angular in the first place ?? simply to implement a piece of dom with some functionality, sin't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a function like that :

```
$scope.myfunction = function(){
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var range = [];
    range.push(year);
    for(var i=1;i<20;i++) {
      range.push(year + i);
    }
    return range;
}
```

and in your HTML :

```
 <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="year for year in myfunction()"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you are missing is the ng-model from the select statement. Here is a working example:

```js
(function() {

  angular
    .module("app", []);

  angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("AppController", AppController);

  AppController.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function AppController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.selectedYear = "";
    vm.years = [];
    loadData();


    function loadData() {
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
      var range = [];
      range.push(year);
      for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        range.push(year + i);
      }
      vm.years = range;
    }





  }


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  
<div>
<select ng-model="vm.selectedYear"ng-options="year for year in vm.years">
</select>

</div>
  


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is also a great answer